# Kohana Error... Attempt to assign property of non-object

Tags: php, kohana

So I'm trying to go through the Version 3 Guide of Kohana and keep getting an error on the hello world create view part.

```
ErrorException [ Warning ]: Attempt to assign property of non-object
Line 8: $this->template->message = 'hello world';
```

I placed the site.php in the application/views folder... is this the wrong place...?

The code....

```
public $template = 'site';

public function action_index()
{
        $this->template->message = 'hello world';
}
```

If anyone can shed some light on what I'm doing wrong I'd much appreciate it... Thanks

Comment: I'm new to StackOverflow and since I answered my own question below should I just delete this post altogether so people don't waste time coming across it? This is a pretty basic mistake... don't know how many would benefit from this being posted....

Comment: Don't worry, I think some that are new to Kohana v3 might make the same mistake :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oops forgot to extend the right controller.

Had

```
class Controller_Welcome extends Controller {
```

Needed to have

```
class Controller_Welcome extends Controller_Template {
```

Answer (score 2):

you may find that you need to add

```
public function before()
{
   parent::before();

}
```

in your Controller_Welcome so that it will pre-load & reference the extended controller